# My raycastHit2D object get null for mouse position in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a code script (c#) in unity2D that when the user clicks mouse on the object and to get the mouse position to make some action, but as in the code first if statement, it works and responds when the mouse is pressed, but in the second if statement it does not work and moves to the else statement.
When I made the debugging , I discovered at the line
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D. Raycast (mousePos2D, Vector2.zero); which give me null , even though the lines before it give me values, I don’t know why?

```
 using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public class click : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
    
            
        }
    
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
    
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                Debug.Log("good 1");
                Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                Vector2 mousePos2D = new Vector2(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
    
                RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mousePos2D, Vector2.zero);
                if (hit.collider != null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("good 2");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("bad ");
                }
    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't shoot a raycasts in direction `Vector2.zero` ... and `null` just means you didn't hit anything ...

Answer (score 0):

Debug.Log(gameObject.name); in if hit.collider

Comment: Debug.Log(gameObject.name);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your elements clicked I think this is what you need:

```
public class click : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Debug.Log("good 1");
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 20, Color.white);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
                if (hit.collider != null) {
                    Debug.Log("good 2");
                }
                else {
                    Debug.Log("bad ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You camera, that should be apart from your 2D scene is in the 3rd dimension, so the world is actually in 3D even if the scene is in 2D. So the raycast should be in 3d afaik. You can play around with `Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 20, Color.white);` to check in the 3d scene hoy the ray is drawn from the corresponding point in the near plane of the camera, to the direction where you clicked, so "fired" or drawn accordingly.
Be sure that the target object has a collider so that the ray hits and you'll see the `Debug.Log("good 2");`

Comment: Thank you and I appreciate your help, I tried it, but it didn't work, but I discovered the solution after many searches, and since I am new to the unity, I did not add a box collider component to the object and when I added ,the code has work ! thank you again .

Comment: You are welcome. That is what I was telling you at the end in the question: `Be sure that the target object has a collider so that the ray hits and you'll see the Debug.Log("good 2");`....